# How to make Babel only ignore top-level node_modules?

Tags: babeljs

I am kinda using `node_modules` folders internally on my package, so I want them compiled by Babel.

NB: I am using the `babel-node` CLI to start the thing.

Comment: Well, you could let babel transpile the whole `node_modules` folder (it'll be slower, but it shouldn't break anything). Or you may write a complex regex `ignore`option with a negative look-ahead to ignore only first level of deps. Though, in this case I would rather suggest using `only` option to restrict `babel` to your `src` folder and one particular package you want to transpile as well.

Answer (score 0):

v2: Made it work using: `"babel-node": "babel-node --only src -- "` using a compromise: No code needing to be transformed by Babel outside the `src` folder. So still, if anybody has better suggestions, please feel free to add an answer.

*v1 original answer:*

Made it work; this is what it looks like in my npm `scripts`:

`"babel-node": "babel-node --only index\\.js,src -- "`

There's also [this bug](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T6726) which prevents me from specifying it in the config instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you using babel only options, It should be added "*" glob pattern and other yourself glob pattern.